# Differential equation for radiation absorption

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation, differential-equations

Let the radiation absorbed by a material be given as a function $N(x)$, where $x$ is the material's layer thickness. In a piece with a thickness of $dx$, $dN$ particles are absorbed. This number is proportional to the number $N(x)$ and to the layer thickness $dx$ with a proportionality constant of $\alpha$.

How can I write down the differential equation for $N(x)$?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $dN$ is proportional to $N(x)$, we must include the beam loss with it's passage through the absorbing medium by a distance $dx$ to get the following:

$$ dN \propto - N(x) dx $$

Rearranging the relation above after inserting the constant of proportionality $\alpha$, you get:

$$ dN = -\alpha N(x) dx$$

Upon rearranging, you get the differential equation:

$$dN/dx + \alpha N(x) = 0$$